# Show desktop grid not working anymore (Ubuntu 20.04 KDE Plasma)

Tags: kde, workspaces, 20.04

Problem: While pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> nothing is happening.

1. Yesterday everything worked perfect.
2. I tried to change shortcut, still nothing is happening.
3. I don't know how to force "show grid" without shortcut, so not sure if it's shortcut fault (I think not).
4. Since yesterday I have done few changes: was messing around with special application setting of few applications, changed named and number of workspace, turned on and off few workspace settings like "navigation wraps around" and "animation when switching", done automatic update without checking what I'm updating, change standard color themes, installed few applications (but none should change any settings if I remember right)

I don't remember anything else that could brake "show window grid", but was fooling around since I'm new to KDE.

I'm not sure where to look, I believe I checked system settings quite thoroughly and could find anything what could turn off workspace grid.

Comment: Did you accidentally disable compositing? `Shift+Alt+F12` toggles compositing on/off.

Comment: No, but it turned out I turned off in Workspace Behavior -> Desktop Effects -> Window management -> Desktop Grid.
Instead I enabled Desktop Cube.
Didn't know those have different shortcuts and can work alongside.

Was looking for answer more than an hour, for real. That's what you got when you get too much configuration options. Still love KDE.

And I actually tried this disable/able compositing since I was able to find this suggestion i google.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @DK Bose Would you like to post and answer (disabling compositing or disabling actually grid in Desktop effects) so I could mark it as right one?

Comment: Please go ahead and post an answer yourself and ping me when you do. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what "ping" is, so I guess i upvote you here?
Again, thank you.

Comment: "ping" at SE sites means using `@` before a username to notify that person. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most probable reasons:

- Disabled compositing - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> (if shortcut not working, you should find this option in System Settings -> Display and monitor -> Compositor. Shortcut may be disabled by system, more in @svenevs )
- Disabled Desktop Grid (I learnt it hard way, that it's something different than Dekstop Cube and have different shortcut - that was answer to my problem). This option is in System Settings -> Workspace ->  Workspace Behavior -> Window Management -> Desktop Grid

Comment: Compositing menu for me was in System Settings -> Display and Monitor -> Compositor, `shift` + `alt` + `F12` does not appear to toggle in the event that the system (somehow) decided to disable it after repeated crashes.  "Compositing recently crashed ... likely driver issues ... re-enable may result in immediate Crash" (say YES)  Pretty clever :D

Comment: Thank you @svenevs, I updated post following your comment.